# Extracting timing of separate words from a continuous wav file

Tags: audio, time, timestamp, wav, praat

I have a long wav file with the repetition of the same syllable (/da/). I recorded two channels in the audio file:

[image: Continuous audio file]

Top - Speech signal
Bottom - Triggers occurring when the syllable was produced

I saved the timing of triggers in another file but now I also need to know when the syllables ended.
The trigger at the beginning is very accurate and is related to other file so I want to keep this timing.

How should I extract the timing when the syllables end? Can it be done in Praat or do I need something else?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to extract timing from the continuous file using Speech Filing System (SFS - http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/resource/sfs/). 
Using GUI it can be located in `Tools>Speech>Annotate>Find multiple endpoints`.

There is also a command line tool which allows automatizing the analysis:
http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/resource/sfs/help/man/npoint.htm

Once the annotation is ready, timing and labels can be extracted to an external file (e.g. txt, csv, or xml).